# Inserting multiple records from one table to another table

Tags: mysql

Iam inserting multiple records from one table to another table like

```
INSERT INTO table3 (
   iSysRecDeleted, 
   iUserId 
) 
SELECT 
   table2.iDeleteId, 
  (SELECT iUserIdOld FROM table1 WHERE table1.col1=table2.col2)
FROM table2
```

But it is giving me "Sub query returns more than 1 row".`iUserIdOld` had multiple entries with repetive in `table1`.Also I have to insert column3 from another table which will be not relevant to table1 and table2 so I don't have to use Join.Could anyone please tell me to do it in a right way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (
   iSysRecDeleted, 
   iUserId 
) 
SELECT table2.iDeleteId, table1.iUserIdOld 
from table2 join table1 on table1.col1=table2.col2
```

Comment: @Gautam3164 That means? There is nothing in your question, that shows your new problem.

Comment: @Jens please see the edited question..Till I dont want to insert 3rd column from another table your query is working fine

Comment: @Gautam3164 Can you show some more deatils so that I can understand the problem? Where the third column comes from and how can you get a single reord from this.